# Any MvxPreferenceFragment Sample Code?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, preferences

Can't seem to get my settings to work on android. Is there a sample showing how to use the `MvxPreferenceFragment`? I'm mostly missing a way to show the `Fragment`, like a `MvxPreferenceActivity`.

Sadly the samples for Android don't use it.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Resources/layout/fragment_settings.axml

I did try it with a "normal" activity (`MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`) but the app just crashes.

Code for my fragment:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(SettingsViewModel), Resource.Id.flContent, true)]
[Register("client.android.fragments.SettingsFragment")]
public class SettingsFragment : MvxPreferenceFragment<SettingsSyncViewModel>
{
    public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle p0, string p1)
    {
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category Title"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="CheckboxStuff"
        android:summary="Checkbox..."
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <Preference
                android:key="pref_key_limit"
                android:summary="Stuff ..."
                android:title="Hello World" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

View models are empty. Just trying to get it to show. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something we should fix in the presenter. What i currently do is open this from within the Android project:

```
//ViewModel is loaded here to support popup fragments
private PreviewViewModel previewViewModel;
public PreviewViewModel ViewModel => previewViewModel = previewViewModel ?? Mvx.IocConstruct<PreviewViewModel>();


public void ShowDetail()
{
   var activity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity as MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity;
   if (activity != null)
   {
     var dialog = new PreviewDialogFragment() { DataContext = ViewModel };
     dialog.Show(activity.SupportFragmentManager, "preview");
   }
}
```